# How to change CFLAGS for autogen.sh

Tags: linux-mint, make, gcc, mdm

I am relatively new to Linux.

I was trying to rebuild MDM display manager for Linux mint from url
https://github.com/linuxmint/mdm.

In the documentation it is said that you should use

```
./autogen.sh --enable-ipv6=yes --with-prefetch
```

If I do that and I do a make I will get this error

> mdm-daemon-config.c:1818:4: error: format not a string literal and no format 
>    arguments [-Werror=format-security]
>
> gchar *s = g_strdup_printf (C_(N_("MDM "
>
> ^

Then I read somewhere that ubuntu is treating this as error. I tried with

```
./autogen.sh --enable-ipv6=yes --with-prefetch CFLAGS="-Wno-format-security"
```

And I got rid of that warning but I got another error:

> mdm-daemon-config.c:2003:1: error: no previous prototype for
>   ‘mdm_daemon_load_config_file’ [-Werror=missing-prototypes] 
>   mdm_daemon_load_config_file (MdmConfig **load_config)  ^

I tried then with

```
./autogen.sh --enable-ipv6=yes --with-prefetch CFLAGS="-Wno-format-security -Wno-missing-prototypes"
```

but that didn't help either. When I do a `make` I see that gcc is using (among other things just copied the interesting part)

> -Wno-missing-prototypes  -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Werror=missing-prototypes

so it is using both -Wno-missing-prototypes and -Werror=missing-prototypes which is probably what is causing it to malfunction.